# tensorflow Throw the output is Value Error

Tags: tensorflow

Is a Problem facing value error in tensorflow why error occurd to the this code:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(training_images, training_labels, epochs=10)
```

I trying to the runtime is my loss function is currectly but why error generate to the model.fit line beacause it is currectly worked.

the error is:

```
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-6a49c32cd601> in <cell line: 5>()
      3               metrics=['accuracy'])
      4 
----> 5 model.fit(training_images, training_labels, epochs=10)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1109, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 240, in __call__
        self.build(y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 182, in build
        self._losses = tf.nest.map_structure(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 353, in _get_loss_object
        loss = losses_mod.get(loss)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 2653, in get
        return deserialize(identifier, use_legacy_format=use_legacy_format)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 2600, in deserialize
        return legacy_serialization.deserialize_keras_object(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/saving/legacy/serialization.py", line 543, in deserialize_keras_object
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Unknown loss function: 'square_categorical_crossentropy'. Please ensure you are using a `keras.utils.custom_object_scope` and that this object is included in the scope. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details.
```

Comment: Code does not match the error, and there is no loss called square_categorical_crossentropy, you probably mean the sparse_categorical_crossentropy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is for working with the Fashion MNIST dataset using TensorFlow and building a simple neural network model for image classification. However, there's a minor issue in your code. You need to preprocess the labels and convert them into one-hot encoded vectors before training the model. Here's the corrected version of your code:

Added that:

```
# Preprocess the labels (one-hot encoding)
training_labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(training_labels, num_classes=10)
test_labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(test_labels, num_classes=10)
```